# Delete Image from URI which store the full size of image

Tags: android

I create the temp folder to store full size image in Android N. How can I delete the image? This code doesn't work on my program.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(NewIssueActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    File file = new File(mHighQualityImageUri.getPath());
                    Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "+++" + mHighQualityImageUri.getPath());
                    file.delete();
                    Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "+++");
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "+++===");
                            file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
                            Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "+++---");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "===");
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
                            Log.d("PostDeleteImage", "----------" + file.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: see `ContentResolver` API

Comment: @pskink so means my code cannot work?

Comment: you wrote `This code doesn't work on my program.`, didnt you?

Comment: @pskink ya, it nv delete

Comment: so check `ContentResolver` docs

Comment: @pskink ok will check it

Comment: @pskink 
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
contentResolver.delete(imageUriLcl, null, null);

if i want delete more than one pic wat shall i do? for loop it?

Comment: `delete` has `where` parameter, you could try that but  i'm not sure if it work... for example `_id in ?, ?, ?` for deleting three ids

Comment: if it does not work you can still of course call `delete` in a loop